# Can't get callback function data from my user model into user router nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, mern

Ive been trying to look at callback functions and async functions for awhile and I still can seem to figure this out.
My users.js file contains all my dynamodb queries and I need to get the queries into my userRouter to register and allow users to do tasks I know passing data back from an async api call is a common issue people have on here I just cant seem to find a solution I can implement.
users.js:

```
AWS = require("aws-sdk");

class UsersModel {

    constructor(r){
        
        AWS = require("aws-sdk");
        console.log(r);
        AWS.config.update({
            region: r,
        });
        this.dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
        this.docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    }


    createUsersTable(){

        var params = {
            TableName : "RestaurantUsers",
            KeySchema: [       
                { AttributeName: "username", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
                { AttributeName: "password", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
            ],
            AttributeDefinitions: [       
                { AttributeName: "username", AttributeType: "S" },
                { AttributeName: "password", AttributeType: "S" }
            ],
            ProvisionedThroughput: {       
                ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
                WriteCapacityUnits: 10
            }
        };
            
        this.dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            }
        });
    }

    addUser(username, password){
        var params = {
            TableName:"RestaurantUsers",
            Item:{
                "username": `${username}`,
                "password": `${password}`,
            }
        };
        
        console.log("Adding a new item...");
        this.docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            }
        });
    }

    login(username, password){
        var params = {
            TableName : "RestaurantUsers",
            Key: {
                "username": username,
                "password": password
            }
        }

        this.docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data.username, null, 2));
            }
        });
        
    }

    checkUser (username) {
        var params = {
            TableName : "RestaurantUsers",
            KeyConditionExpression: "#usern = :u",
            ExpressionAttributeNames:{
                "#usern": "username"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":u": username
            }
        };
        
        var result = this.docClient.query(params, function(err, data, callback) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("Data items: " + data.Items.length) + typeof data.Items
                
                console.log(result.constructor)
                return data;
            }
        });
        
        console.log("Result: " + result);
        return result;
    }

}


module.exports.UsersModel = UsersModel;
```

and my usersRouter.js where I want to use my data looks like this:

```
    const router = require("express").Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
//Database UserModel
const Users = require("../models/users");
const u = new Users.UsersModel("us-east-1");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try {

        let {username, password, passwordCheck} = req.body;

        //validation
        if(!username || !password || !passwordCheck)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: "Not all fields have been entered."});

        if(password.length < 5 && password.length > 20)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: "The password needs to be between 5 - 20 characters long."})

        if(password != passwordCheck)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: "Make sure both password fields match."})

        let existingUser = u.checkUser(username)
        console.log("existing user: " + existingUser);
    
        if(existingUser)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: "This account already exists"})

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();

        const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        u.addUser(username, passwordHash);

    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message + "on register"});
    }
    res.send("Hello World");
});

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let {username, password} = req.body;

        if(!username || !password)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: "Not all fields have been entered."});

        if(password.length < 5 && password.length > 20)
            return res.status(400).json({msg: "The password needs to be between 5 - 20 characters long."});

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
        const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        if(u.login(username, passwordHash))
            return res.status(400).json({msg: "This account already exists"});

    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have been working with the checkUser() specifically.
Anyone know a way to do this?